# Electrical Outlet in Wall Covered by Mirror - Risks

Tags: electrical

I have a relatively new house (5 years old) and am thinking of hanging a large mirror over an electrical outlet. I don't have a need for the electrical outlet in that area, so I'm fine from a usage perspective, but want to know about risks. I've looked into it, and the outlet will continue to be accessible (mirror will come off easily but very rarely), so I want to know if I should:

1. Leave the outlet fully covered with mirror (unless there are any safety issues), or
2. Should I cap the outlet instead?

Please advise.

Comment: The mirror stands off enough from the wall that it doesn't get tilted out by resting on the receptacle faceplate, right?

Comment: You could install a recessed receptacle, but if you don't need the receptacle it would be unnecessary trouble. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0012DKBL2/ref=asc_df_B0012DKBL25089006/?tag=hyprod-20&creative=394997&creativeASIN=B0012DKBL2&linkCode=df0&hvadid=167140365824&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=4364572757350965582&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9026945&hvtargid=pla-307234194376 How far from the floor is the bottom of the mirror and how far is the receptacle? Is this a full length mirror?

Comment: Is the mirror easily movable as part of its ordinary usage?  Or will it be affixed to the wall somehow?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Mirror is flush against the wall, but doesn't get titled out by the receptacle faceplate - it's likely touching the paper that covers the middle of the back of the mirror.

Comment: @Harper mirror is affixed to the wall towards the top of the mirror - it's a full length mirror, with the bottom of the mirror about an inch off the baseboards. Bottom of the receptacle is about 6-ish inches off he top of the baseboards.

Answer (score 4):

You're fine just so long as the receptacles is accessible and as long as you can take the mirror down to service it as need be I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Nope.  "Affixed" is the magic word.

You can't cover any part of any junction box, receptacle included, by any installed part of the house.  The farthest you can possibly push that rule is a false back on a bookshelf where you can remove the books and shelves and false back with your hands... but even then some AHJs may reject it.